# Is it possible to share state with a node of another parentage tree?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Without using redux-saga, just with react hooks, context api and others, is it possible to share states with a node on the other side of the tree?

For example:
We have a **sheet number (1)** and it has a select that is a form, if necessary on the **sheet (5)**, get the selected value of that select (form) and use this value for another matter.

[image]

An example in real code is as follows...

I created a custom component called "`SwitchRoute`" and it has a routing structure:

```
<Switch>
 <Route />
</Switch>
```

Within one of these `<Route />` the select form component is rendered, which is **sheet number 1 (not developed at the moment)**;

Inside another of these `<Route />` will be the page, where you will find a form, which I need these values ​​to proceed, which is **sheet number 5**;

**CODE:**

```
const HomePage = () => (
    <MainContainer>
        <PanelSection>
            <SwitchRoute
                list={[
                    { key: 'select-structure', exact: true, path: '/new', children: <div>New</div> }, // SHEET NUMBER (1)
                    { key: 'filter-quotation', exact: true, path: '/stored', children: <div> </div> },
                ]}
            />
        </PanelSection>

        <ContentSection>
            <SectionTitle>
                <Navigation />
            </SectionTitle>

            <SwitchRoute
                list={[
                    { key: 'new-quotation-section', exact: true, path: '/new', children: NewPage }, // SHEET NUMBER (5)
                    { key: 'stored-quotation-section', exact: true, path: '/stored', children: StoredPage },
                ]}
            />
        </ContentSection>
    </MainContainer>
);
```

Comment: Asking whether something is good practice is asking for an opinion, which is off-topic. People on Stack Overflow will tell you if they believe a practice is bad or even not very good.

Comment: In terms of technical terms (code), what would you do?

Comment: Yes, it's possible with just a React context. It's a bit easier when also using the `useContext` React hook. What you are asking is possible is really just an implementation of [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Move the state to a common ancestor (node 4 possibly), and provide the state via props passed down or via a React context.

Comment: Hi Drew, you are here again with your genius! Node 4 would be the parent component (HomePage), I was thinking of putting the Provider like this: `<MainContainer><Provider>....</Provider></MainContainer>`

But I'm not sure if it would be correct that way, as it would be encompassing components that don't need it, but that's the only way I see...

Comment: That is sort of the idea with React Contexts, they wrap *entire* chunks of the ReactTree and only the descendent components interested in the context values needs to access the context.